# Core Data : inserting Objects crashed in global queue [ARC - iPhone simulator 6.1]

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I have a very simple Core Data demo, in which there is only one button.

When I click the 'run' button, the App creates 10,000 objects in a for-loop, which is **running in the global queue**.

***Update for more detail : If I put the for-loop in main thread, it runs well.***

***Update for my intent : I know that MOC is not thread-safe, but according to [the Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW39), we can also use serial queue to access the MOC, and the serial queue uses more than one threads.***

Here I create the Core Data stack:

```
#pragma mark - Core Data Stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (nil != _managedObjectContext) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

    if (self.persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (nil != _managedObjectModel) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (nil != _persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString *storeType = NSSQLiteStoreType;
    NSString *storeName = @"model.sqlite";
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:storeName]];

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:storeType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:nil
                                                           error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@\n", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSAssert1(YES, @"Failed to create store %@ with NSSQLiteStoreType", [storeURL path]);
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application's Documents Directory

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

after app has launched :

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if (self.managedObjectContext) {
        ;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

When I click the button :

```
- (IBAction)runButtonDidClick:(id)sender
{
    /**
     * Access the moc using different threads to make deadlock.
     */

    [self runSave];
}

- (void)runSave
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        if (moc) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
                People *people = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                people.name = @"noname";
            }

            NSLog(@"**********IN SAVE %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([moc save:&error]) {
                ;
            }

            NSLog(@"**********OUT SAVE %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        }
    });
}
```

For clicking the run button some times, maybe 2 or 3 or 4... It crashes

I could not figure out why...
Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A NSManagedObjectContext is not thread-safe. Why do you intentionally use it on a *concurrent* queue, so that the same MOC will be used on different threads? - And how are we to understand the comment *"Access the moc using different threads to make deadlock."* ?? - Btw. I do not see where you actually create a persistent store.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I actually intentionally use the MOC in different threads & The sqlite file has been created. I know that MOC is not thread-safe, but here, I just access the MOC when the button is clicked. One access, one thread, similar to serial queue?

Comment: @JasonLee right - thread does not matter to MOC but it should be always the same thread

Comment: `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` returns a *concurrent* queue, not a serial queue. A concurrent queue uses *multiple threads* to execute things concurrently.

Comment: @SimpleMan yes, but threads can access the MOC one by one, right?

Comment: @MartinR you're right. But here, the global queue will only dispatch one task when the run button was clicked once :) And the concurrent queue will run one task on one thread, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core data should be always work on thread witch have moc.
the only job for `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` is that take care of thread safety. With it inserting to Core Data will always running in the right thread. You can define moc on whatever thread you want - `performBlock` always choose the right one.

So:

```
[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            for(NSDictionary *dic in arr) {
                //inserting here!
            }
}];
```

In your case:

```
- (void)runSave
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        if (moc) {

          [moc performBlock:^{
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
                People *people = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                people.name = @"noname";
            }
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([moc save:&error]) {
                ;
            }
         }];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks But how about serial queue? The serial queue is using more than one thread.

Comment: I add this to my answer: the only job for `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` is that take care of thread safety. With it inserting to Core Data will always running in the right thread. You can define moc on whatever thread you want - `performBlock` always choose the right one.